# Database Scheme for a Cabling Database

Tags: sql, design-patterns, database-design

I am currently developing a signal database for my work.  The purpose of this database is to track all signals that are interfaced (inputs or outputs) to our computer processing system.  These signals are either hardwired analog signals (e.g. 4-20mA) or they can be digital signals (i.e. ethernet).  We also want to link the signals to all the components that they flow through, from start to end point.  This will allow us do failure analysis on what signals we would lose if X cable was damaged.

I came up with a basic scheme that allows me to capture a single signal flow path by abstracting my tables to inherit what I call a physical table.  The physical table represents everything that is a physical object (i.e. components, insntrumentation, connectors) and having this table store the ID for Path-1 that was assinged in the Paths table.  However this gets complicated when I start assigning multiple paths that flow over a singel cable.  With trunk cables (multiple wire pairs) I figure it would be easy as I could add in a wire pair table to store the ID of the path, however I can't do this with a digital bus cable that could have thousands of signals running over the same strands.

What would be the best way to structure this so that I can query against Signal X and the database will tell me all the components, cables, connectors, etc. that the signals flows through?

Sorry I can't upload images of my idea from my work computer.

**Edit: Adding more information**

I've been doing some more reading and it looks like what I need is the ability to save a graph in a SQL style database.  Right now all I have at my disposal is MS Access (don't make fun).  I do not need to traverse the graph the find the shortest path.  I just want to save the graph with all the components that a signal flows over.  The signal paths will be known based on other design documents we produce at work.  Is it possible to save a graph structure with static premade paths in a relational database like MS Access.  I know this may be overall complicated and processor heavy, so I'm open to suggestion on how I can pull this off.

P.S. I'm a relatively new engineer for my company and do have database and SQL experience from creating websites on my free time in college.  I might not be an expert but I know I can build databases.

**Edit #2 - Thanks to @Randy for giving me a starting point.  Came up with a basic design**

```
Physical (Base Class Table)
-----------------------------------
   ID_Phys (PK)
   (Other Generic Info)

Component (Inherits Physical)
-----------------------------------
   ID_Comp (PK/Index #)  
   ID_Phys (FK)
   Max Terminals
   Is Junction Box (Yes/No)
   (Other Info)

Cable (Inherits Physical)
-----------------------------------
   ID_Cable (PK/Index #)  
   ID_Phys (FK)
   Harness Cable Number
   Cable Type
   (Other Info)

Connector (Inherits Physical)
-----------------------------------
   ID_Conn (PK/Index #)  
   ID_Phys (FK)
   Connector Number
   Connector Type
   # of Pins
   (Other Info)

Instrument (Inherits Physical)
-----------------------------------
   ID_Inst (PK/Index #)  
   ID_Phys (FK)
   Instrument Number
   Signal Type
   (Other Info)

Interface Points 
-----------------------------------
   ID_InterPts (PK / Index #)
   ID_Phys_Origin (FK-Physical)
   ID_Phys_Destination (FK-Physical)

Signal Flow Path Sequence
-----------------------------------
   ID_PathSeq (PK / Index #)
   ID_FlowPath (FKl)
   ID_Phys (FK-Physical)
   Squence # (1,2,3,4,etc)

Signal Flow Path
-----------------------------------
   ID_FlowPath (PK / Index #)
   (Other Info)
```

Signal Flow path is a One-many with Signal Flow Sequence.  Interface Points stores the connections between source and destination material.  Physical is a generic table that will allow me to represent anything that connects to our harness regardless of material type.  I know the Interface Points table and the Signal Flor Path Sequence table are similar.  I figured that I could query against a signal flow path just to get the material with out having to recursive queries since the flow path is preloaded in the Signal Flow Path Sequence table.  If I really wanted to know the order that they connect to each other I would query the results against the interface points table.

Does this seem like a good step forward?

Comment: You might want to think about how you are going to define and resolve routing differences between the different types of Signals. How you choose to approach that, will in large part determine how to best address the issues that you raise above.

Comment: You will probably need self-referential tables and link-tables (junction tables) Recursive queries will be needed to retrieve "exploded bill-of-materials" type queries, which are needed to retrieve al the devices that are present on a particular signal path. This will be hard stuff for a newcomer in database modelling.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

```
node
-----------
node_id
node_type
name

data_packet
------------
data_packet_id
data_packet_type
(other info)

data_flow
------------
producer_node_id
consumer_node_id
data_packet_id
(other info)
```